# How do I get the Social Security Administration to Issue a Corrected 1099?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, social-security, form-1099

When my father passed away the funeral home didn't notify the Social Security Administration. He received 2 direct deposits before we noticed. I had the bank send these back. We received a letter asking why the payments were returned with a phone number to call: 866-397-4239 (post-entitlement). I have called many times over 3 days, nobody will answer the phone. I have left messages, but nobody has returned my call.

I called the normal SSA number (800-772-1213) and they said that since the payments were returned in 2022, they won't issue a corrected SSA-1099 for 2021. When I persisted, they said that they would do me a "favor" and submit a special request, no promises though. Near zero chance of this helping IMO.

1. I could write off the tax for the extra month of payment. If I was the only heir, this would be an acceptable choice to me. A few hundred dollars is not worth fighting for hours and hours.
2. I could subtract the returned payment from the 1099 amount on the tax return. I have a receipt from the bank. However, the IRS may reject the return and I would need to ammend the return. (my experience with the IRS has not been good)

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called the local Social Security office to make an appointment. They weren't taking appointments due to Covid, but they fixed it for me! I got a corrected SSA-1099 in the mail. The moral of the story when dealing with government agencies. Try different approaches when one fails.

Comment: How long did it take to get the corrected SSA1099?

Comment: @Veronica - about 3 weeks.